# How to filter a directory listing with a regular expression in Clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

Given a regex and a directory path, how do I get a seq of files whose path matches the regex?

i.e., I want

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(regex-file-seq #"\.ssh/.*\.pub$" (io/file "/home")) =>
(#<File /home/x/.ssh/iaf_dsa.pub> #<File ....>)
```

This took me a few minutes to put the pieces together, so I thought I'd post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defn regex-file-seq
  "Lazily filter a directory based on a regex."
  [re dir]
  (filter #(re-find re (.getPath %)) (file-seq dir)))
```

Comment: Just use it like: ``(regex-file-seq #".*\.clj" (clojure.java.io/file dir-path))``

Comment: I tried to use it in the repl but I couldn't consume the sequence. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: seq or one of the do-* fns to force the lazy seq, off the top of my head.  All the caveats about lazy seqs apply...

Comment: What if you want to operate on subdirectories as well? This is something that the `clj-glob` does do.

Answer (score 3):

[clj-glob](https://github.com/jkk/clj-glob) can do that for you:

```
(glob "*.{jpg,gif}")
```

Comment: I looked at that.  I was a little put off since there had been no commits in two years.  It also wasn't quite what I needed in this particular case.

Comment: This library works, but one problem with it is that it coerces each path to a file. What if you want just the path strings (for example to use in some other way like opening a FileInputStream)?